# Javascript Snake Game (Prevent reverse while maintaining responsiveness)

Tags: javascript

I have a snake game that's "finished" except for one pretty serious annoyance.

Previously, I had the following problem. 
Say the snake is going right. If the player changed directions multiple times in quick succession, e.g., by pressing down then left, then the snake would go back into itself and reverse direction. Once I added collision detection code, this would cause the game to end and the player to lose because the snake collided with itself by going inward into itself. This problem was made possible because direction could be changed multiple times in one interval, e.g., from right to down then from down to left.

This problem was fixed by adding a bool that would store whether or not direction was allowed to change this interval. If the direction had not been changed yet this interval, then direction was allowed to change. If it had already been changed this interval, then it would have to wait until next interval to change again. This prevented the snake from ever going inward into itself because it guaranteed that the snake's direction could only change once per interval. But this created another problem in that in each interval, every key press after the first would not register.

Now, the problem is that the game no longer feels responsive. If the snake is going to the right, there is no reason that spamming down right in quick succession shouldn't do what the player expects. As it stands, the second right sometimes doesn't register because it was pressed too quickly (on the same interval as down was pressed). So by fixing one big issue in this way, I created another annoyance. How do I get the best of both worlds. How do I stay rid of the possibility to go inward into myself while restoring responsiveness?

I can provide code if necessary, but I thought that the question was pretty clear even in abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the game either acts on the new direction in the next interval or the direction is lost until the user presses again.

Have you tried queuing the next direction? for instance, at every interval, you can check the queue to see if there is a new direction. If there is, change direction. If not, continue in the current direction.

This will probably accomplish the responsiveness you want while still being accurate to the user’s input.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying if I press multiple keys before next interval, store that in a queue. Then next interval, apply the first in direction, the interval after that, apply the next in direction, etc.? Or, in other words, have the queue always apply the next in queue direction and then shift it?

Comment: Right, that’s the idea

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem! Very annoying! I ended up implementing a queue, where recent keypresses are stored in a queue, and for each 'tick' I check if any elements in queue, and if so, shift it once (with Array.shift, which returns the shifted value) and then set the snakes's direction to the direction from the queue, like this:

```
if (dir_queue.length) {
    let d = dir_queue.shift();

    dx = d.dx;
    dy = d.dy;
}
// move snake
x += dx;
y += dy;
```

Directions are pushed to the dir. queue in the keydown event handler, like this:

```
var key = evt.keyCode;
if (key === KEY.UP || key === KEY.DOWN || key === KEY.LEFT || key === KEY.RIGHT) {
    switch (key) {
        case 37:
            dx = dx || -1; dy = 0;
            break;
        case 38:
            dx = 0; dy = dy || -1;
            break;
        case 39:
            dx = dx || 1; dy = 0;
            break;
        case 40:
            dx = 0; dy = dy || 1;
    }
    // push to dir. queue
    dir_queue.push({ dx: dx, dy: dy });
}
```